# git azure deployment rebuild even on develop

Tags: git, azure, azure-web-app-service, continuous-deployment

I work on a mvc5 app deploy on an **azure application** web with a b1 server.
I am using azure **local git repository** with visualstudio2013 git plugging or git cmd lines to manage my code on https://mygituser@mysite.scm.azurewebsites.net:443/mysite.git).
I configured the app for deploy the **master** branch (continuous deployment).

The problem is each time I push on my branch **develop**. Just after the push finish, my website is unavailable during few minutes same as I was pushing on **master**. Almost like it was rebuild my app.

Has anyone got this kind of problem?

thanks by advance

Comment: Can you clarify the exact kind of deployment that you set up? e.g. is it 'Local Git', 'GitHub', 'Visual Studio Online', etc...?

Comment: Sorry if it wasn't clear. I just edited my post. I use a local git repository.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, that is a known issue in the Local Git case, that you can read more about on https://github.com/projectkudu/kudu/issues/538.

The reason it was never fixed is that it really shouldn't happen in practice. If you only want to deploy the master branch, then there is no reason to ever push a different branch to Azure.

Note that the Azure repo is not designed to be the 'source of truth' for you files. Its only purpose is to enable deployment. Users typically have their code on GitHub, VS Team Services, Bitbucket, etc...

Comment: Thanks for your help. It's quite a shame to let's the user be able to make different branches in this case.

Comment: I'm not sure I follow. Can you explain your scenario, and why you need to push branches that you don't intend to deploy?

Comment: I use it as a simple git repo with a classic workflow. master (prod), Inte (fixed dev version), develop. Only the master branch should be deploy on prod. The others are for devs. I was mixing repo for code and repo for continus deployment

Comment: Do you mean that you use the Azure repo as your primary source of truth? Generally, we do not recommend this. Note that you'll get a much nicer experience on a true git host like GitHub, like having a Web UI to view your changes, make pull requests, file issues, ...